# Sortable Js is not working in chrome with Select/Option tag but working fine with ul/li tags

Tags: javascript, rubaxa-sortable

I need a help in sorting my text according their order. I have used Sortable js for sorting their order. I have implement it in select/option tag. Its working fine in mozilla but in chrome it doesnot work. But When i am using ul/li tag then its working fine in both browser. Can any one help me to do this task in select/option tag.

**This is the demo:** https://rubaxa.github.io/Sortable/
**This is files link:** https://github.com/RubaXa/Sortable

Thnaks in Advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head></head> 
<body> 
<select id="foo1" multiple> 
<option value="1">Sunny Thakur</option> 
<option value="2">Deepak kanyan</option> 
<option value="3">Harpreet Singh</option> 
<option value="4">karmjeet Singh</option> 
<option value="5">Gurvinder Singh</option> 
</select> 
<script src="Sortable.js"></script> 
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script> 
<script src="st/app.js"></script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post your html structure and the JavaScript Code you used to initialize the sortable library?

Comment: you can get js files from the link i have mention above. Thanks for replay me.

Comment: Thanks for the posting the html. You should edit your answer and post it in there. Once you post it in your answer you can select the code you posted and then click the {} icon  and it will format your html as code so everyone can see it in a more readable format.

Comment: Thanks for guide me.

Comment: Not a problem, I have set up a basic testing environment I will see what I can figure out.

Comment: I reproduced the problem and confirmed that it doesn't work on chrome in my testing machine either.  Now we have to try and figure out why.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I look forward for the solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems like there is a possible issue with chrome all together with dragging and dropping select list elements. I will see if there is a work around and I will get back to later today if I can.

Comment: I believe I have a solution that is workable for you.  It will take a little extra setup but if you need to have a sortable select list that works in Chrome with Sortable then this is the only solution I can come up with right now.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I can come up with right now is to create your own custom select list widget using JavaScript and CSS. It is a concept I borrowed from the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/How_to_build_custom_form_widgets). Here is a link to the live version of it that you can test in Chrome ([Sortable Select List in Chrome](http://codepen.io/larryjoelane/pen/aNOqLN)).

**HTML**

```
<form class="no-widget">
  <select name="myFruit">
    <option>Cherry</option>
    <option>Lemon</option>
    <option>Banana</option>
    <option>Strawberry</option>
    <option>Apple</option>
  </select>

  <div class="select" role="listbox">
    <span class="value">Cherry</span>
    <ul id="myList" class="optList hidden" role="presentation">
      <li class="option" role="option" aria-selected="true">Cherry</li>
      <li class="option" role="option">Lemon</li>
      <li class="option" role="option">Banana</li>
      <li class="option" role="option">Strawberry</li>
      <li class="option" role="option">Apple</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
.widget select,
.no-widget .select {
  position : absolute;
  left     : -5000em;
  height   : 0;
  overflow : hidden;
}

/* --------------- */
/* Required Styles */
/* --------------- */

.select {
  position: relative;
  display : inline-block;
}

.select.active,
.select:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px 1px #227755;
  outline: none;
}

.select .optList {
  position: absolute;
  top     : 100%;
  left    : 0;
}

.select .optList.hidden {
  max-height: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

/* ------------ */
/* Fancy Styles */
/* ------------ */

.select {
  font-size   : 0.625em; /* 10px */
  font-family : Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;

  -moz-box-sizing : border-box;
  box-sizing : border-box;

  padding : 0.1em 2.5em 0.2em 0.5em; /* 1px 25px 2px 5px */
  width   : 10em; /* 100px */

  border        : 0.2em solid #000; /* 2px */
  border-radius : 0.4em; /* 4px */

  box-shadow : 0 0.1em 0.2em rgba(0,0,0,.45); /* 0 1px 2px */

  background : #F0F0F0;
  background : -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, #E3E3E3, #fcfcfc 50%, #f0f0f0);
  background : linear-gradient(0deg, #E3E3E3, #fcfcfc 50%, #f0f0f0);
}

.select .value {
  display  : inline-block;
  width    : 100%;
  overflow : hidden;

  white-space   : nowrap;
  text-overflow : ellipsis;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.select:after {
  content : "▼";
  position: absolute;
  z-index : 1;
  height  : 100%;
  width   : 2em; /* 20px */
  top     : 0;
  right   : 0;

  padding-top : .1em;

  -moz-box-sizing : border-box;
  box-sizing : border-box;

  text-align : center;

  border-left  : .2em solid #000;
  border-radius: 0 .1em .1em 0;

  background-color : #000;
  color : #FFF;
}

.select .optList {
  z-index : 2;

  list-style: none;
  margin : 0;
  padding: 0;

  background: #f0f0f0;
  border: .2em solid #000;
  border-top-width : .1em;
  border-radius: 0 0 .4em .4em;

  box-shadow: 0 .2em .4em rgba(0,0,0,.4);

  -moz-box-sizing : border-box;
  box-sizing : border-box;

  min-width : 100%;
  max-height: 10em; /* 100px */
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.select .option {
  padding: .2em .3em;
}

.select .highlight {
  background: #000;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
// ------- //
// HELPERS //
// ------- //

NodeList.prototype.forEach = function(callback) {
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(this, callback);
}

// -------------------- //
// Function definitions //
// -------------------- //

function deactivateSelect(select) {
  if (!select.classList.contains('active')) return;

  var optList = select.querySelector('.optList');

  optList.classList.add('hidden');
  select.classList.remove('active');
}

function activeSelect(select, selectList) {
  if (select.classList.contains('active')) return;

  selectList.forEach(deactivateSelect);
  select.classList.add('active');
};

function toggleOptList(select, show) {
  var optList = select.querySelector('.optList');

  optList.classList.toggle('hidden');
}

function highlightOption(select, option) {
  var optionList = select.querySelectorAll('.option');

  optionList.forEach(function(other) {
    other.classList.remove('highlight');
  });

  option.classList.add('highlight');
};

function updateValue(select, index) {
  var nativeWidget = select.previousElementSibling;
  var value = select.querySelector('.value');
  var optionList = select.querySelectorAll('.option');

  optionList.forEach(function(other) {
    other.setAttribute('aria-selected', 'false');
  });

  optionList[index].setAttribute('aria-selected', 'true');

  nativeWidget.selectedIndex = index;
  value.innerHTML = optionList[index].innerHTML;
  highlightOption(select, optionList[index]);
};

function getIndex(select) {
  var nativeWidget = select.previousElementSibling;

  return nativeWidget.selectedIndex;
};

// ------------- //
// Event binding //
// ------------- //

window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  var form = document.querySelector('form');

  form.classList.remove("no-widget");
  form.classList.add("widget");
});

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var selectList = document.querySelectorAll('.select');

  selectList.forEach(function(select) {
    var optionList = select.querySelectorAll('.option'),
      selectedIndex = getIndex(select);

    select.tabIndex = 0;
    select.previousElementSibling.tabIndex = -1;

    updateValue(select, selectedIndex);

    optionList.forEach(function(option, index) {
      option.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
        highlightOption(select, option);
      });

      option.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        updateValue(select, index);
      });
    });

    select.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      toggleOptList(select);
    });

    select.addEventListener('focus', function(event) {
      activeSelect(select, selectList);
    });

    select.addEventListener('blur', function(event) {
      deactivateSelect(select);
    });

    select.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
      var length = optionList.length,
        index = getIndex(select);

      if (event.keyCode === 40 && index < length - 1) {
        index++;
      }
      if (event.keyCode === 38 && index > 0) {
        index--;
      }

      updateValue(select, index);
    });
  });
});

//initialize Sortable
var list = document.getElementById("myList");

Sortable.create(list);
```